# Can't Assign to Literal in Python

Tags: python

I'm receiving an error in python that says I, "Can't assign to literal". I was hoping that somebody could help me understand why this is coming up. Here's my code:

```
# Chapter 3 Challenge part 3
# use the code below and the following
# directions to see if you can solve the problem

# Your Co-Worker has been asked to write a
#   1st time "Log-in" program in which a user has to
#    sign in with their user name. If they enter
#    the correct id name they need to be asked
#    to create their password.

#   They were required to make sure the user did
#   not leave the username entry blank and must have the
#   correct user name or the progam should re-ask
#   them to sign in... They cannot figure out what
#   to do, so they have called on you to help...

#   Here is what they have so far...
#   They started their program like this....
#   and included some of their documentation.



# Get username, check to see if not empty,
# then verify that username is correct.
# using username "jalesch" as test user.
name = False
while not name:
    name = raw_input("Enter your user name: ")

print "Welcome," , name ,  "you must create a password."

password = False

while not password:
    password = raw_input("""Enter a password.
Password must be at least 6 characters in length,
and must include one of these symbols (!, $, ?, &): """)
    while len(password) < 6:
        for "!" in password or "$" in password or "?" in password or "&" in password:
            password = raw_input("""Enter a password.
Password must be at least 6 characters in length,
and must include one of these symbols (!, $, ?, &): """)

    print "This has met the requirements."

check = raw_input("Please re-enter your password:")
while check != password:
    print "You have entered the wrong password"
    check = raw_input("Please re-enter your password:")
print "Welcome to the program!"


# prompt user to create a password that meets the
# following requirements:
#       - Must be at least 6 characters in length
#       - Must include at least one of these 4 symbols
#           - ! $ ? &
# Once the user has entered their password, the program
#  must check to see if it meets the requirements.
#   If the requirements are not met, it should reask them
#   to put in a password that meets the requirements
#   until they get it correct.
#   Test password is:  $program!

#   If it meets the requirements then prompt the user
#   to re enter the password, and check that the
#   first and second entry matches.
#       If the 1st and 2nd match. display "Welcome to the program"
#       If the 1st and 2nd don't match, re-prompt for the password
#       until they get a correct match.
```

I also believe that the code is malfunctioning when I try to find the special characters, because it is skipping one of the while loops.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on this line:

```
for "!" in password or "$" in password or "?" in password or "&" in password:
```

You probably meant to use `if`:

```
if "!" in password or "$" in password or "?" in password or "&" in password:
```

`for x in y` iterates over `y`, assigning each member to `x` sequentially, running the following indented code in a loop for each member of `y`. You can't assign a value to `"!"` because that's a *literal* character, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_name(prompt):
    while True:
        name = raw_input(prompt).strip()
        if name:
            return name

def get_password(prompt):
    while True:
        name = raw_input(prompt).strip()
        if len(name) >= 6 and (set(name) & set("!$?&")):
            return name

name = get_name("Enter your user name: ")
print("Welcome, {}, you must create a password.".format(name))

while True:
    print("Now enter a password. It must be at least 6 characters in length, and must include a symbols (!, $, ?, &).")
    pass1 = get_password("Enter a password: ")
    pass2 = get_password("Please re-enter your password: ")

    if pass1 == pass2:
        print("Welcome to the program")
        break
    else:
        print("No match! Please try again")
```